# codeigniter data not inserting

Tags: codeigniter

My Controller:

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Product extends CI_Controller
{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        //$this->load->library('session');
        $config['upload_path']    = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types']  = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $this->load->library('upload',$config);
        $this->load->model('Pro_model');
    }
    public function NewProduct(){
        $data['categories'] = $this->Pro_model->fetchCat();
        $data['upload_error'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                //var_dump($cat_res); exit;
                $this->load->view('common/header');
                $this->load->view('common/sidebar');
                $this->load->view('addnewpro',$data);
                $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }
    public function Pro_insert(){
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('proname','Product Name','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('prodesc','Product Description','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('proprice','Product Price','required');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('procat','Product Category','required');
            if ($this->form_validation->run() && $this->upload->do_upload('proimg')) {  
                $post = $this->input->post();
                 unset($post['submit']);
                //var_dump($post); exit;
                $data = $this->upload->data();
                $img_path = base_url("upload/".$data['raw_name'].$data['file_ext']);
                //var_dump($img_path); exit;
                $post['img_path'] = $img_path;

                 $post_data = $this->Pro_model->insert_product($post);
                // var_dump($pro_data); exit;
                 if ($post_data) {
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('prosuccess','Product Insert Success');
                    //redirect('Product/Pro_insert');
                    $this->NewProduct();
                 }
                 else{
                    $this->NewProduct();
                 }
            }

            else{

                $this->NewProduct();
            }
    }

}
```

My model:

```
<?php
/**
* 
*/
class Pro_model extends CI_Model
{

    public function insert_product($post){

        return $this->db->insert('product',$post);

         //echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;

    }
    public function fetchCat()
    {   
        $res = $this->db->get('category');
        //echo $this->db->last_query(); exit;
        return $res->result();
    }
}
```

My View:

```
            <!-- MAIN CONTENT-->
            <div class="main-content">
                <div class="section__content section__content--p30">
                    <div class="container-fluid">
                    <?php
                    if ($this->session->flashdata('prosuccess')) { ?>
                    <div class="alert alert-success">
                    <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('prosuccess'); } ?></div>
                        <div class="row">   
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                            <form action="<?php echo base_url('product/Pro_insert'); ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                <div class="card">
                                    <div class="card-header">
                                        <strong>Add New</strong> Product
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-body card-block">

                                        <div class="has-success form-group">
                                            <label for="inputIsValid" class=" form-control-label">Product Name</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="proname" class="is-valid form-control-success form-control">
                                           <div style="color: red"><?php echo form_error('proname'); ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="has-warning form-group">
                                            <label for="inputIsInvalid" class=" form-control-label">Product Description</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="prodesc" class="is-invalid form-control">
                                           <div style="color: red"> <?php echo form_error('prodesc'); ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                         <div class="has-warning form-group">
                                            <label for="inputIsInvalid" class=" form-control-label">Product Price</label>
                                            <input type="text" name="proprice" class="is-invalid form-control">
                                           <div style="color: red"> <?php echo form_error('proprice'); ?></div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="has-warning form-group">

                                        <label for="inputIsInvalid" class=" form-control-label">Product Category</label>
                                        <select name="procat" class="is-invalid form-control">
                                        <?php 
                                            foreach ($categories as $cat) { ?>
                                               <option value="<?php echo $cat->cat_id; ?>"><?php echo $cat->cat_name; ?></option>  
                                               <?php } ?>
                                          <div style="color: red"> <?php echo form_error('procat'); ?></div>
                                        </select>
                                        </div>

                                        <div class="has-warning form-group">
                                            <label for="inputIsInvalid" class=" form-control-label">Product Image</label>
                                            <input type="file" name="proimg" class="is-invalid">
                                            <?php if ($upload_error) {
                                              echo $upload_error;
                                            } ?>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="card-footer">
                                        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>

                        </div>
```

> My Error is:
>
> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1054
>
> Unknown column 'proname' in 'field list'
>
> INSERT INTO `product` (`proname`, `prodesc`, `proprice`, `procat`,
>   `img_path`) VALUES ('sultan', 'ali', '2323', '11',
>   'http://localhost/shop/Admin/upload/Penguins7.jpg')
>
> Filename: G:/xampp/htdocs/shop/Admin/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

Comment: Check 'proname' column name in database table.

Answer (score 0):

May be your have spelled the field name incorrectly... 
Check with the table